# How do I retrieve a URL stored in a Firebase database and then populate an image tag's src?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have followed a good tutorial on how to create a Firebase database. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmTECF0JZyQ) Then I have managed to retrieved this data to show on my webpage. Working with text and numbers is clear but what happens when I want to render an image on my HTML page? Images are served from on my site.

Therefore, I can use a text field to store the URL of an image but how would I then show this on my page as the  tag is created but obvisously not the 'src' to populate the URL. Any help welcome.

```
const productList = document.querySelector('#productList');

function renderProducts(doc) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let title = document.createElement('span');
    let price = document.createElement('span');
    let image = document.createElement('img');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    title.textContent = doc.data().title;
    price.textContent = doc.data().price;
    image.textContent = doc.data().image;

    li.appendChild(title);
    li.appendChild(price);
    li.appendChild(image);

    productList.appendChild(li);
}

db.collection('Products').orderBy('title').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderProducts(doc);
    })
})
```

Comment: maybe I got it wrong ... why don't you set the src attribute equal to the image URL - `image.setAttribute(imgUrl)`?

Comment: Thank you Doug. I was aware that the img tag was being created but didnt know you could target the src of an image like in your answer. I have updated my code to the below and it works! Thanks for your help, really helps my to learn and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` elements don't have a textContent property.  I imagine you meant to use [img.src](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp) this to load a URL into the `img`:

```
image.src = doc.data().image;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const productList = document.querySelector('#productList');

function renderProducts(doc) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let title = document.createElement('span');
    let price = document.createElement('span');
    let image = document.createElement('img');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    title.textContent = doc.data().title;
    price.textContent = doc.data().price;
    image.src = doc.data().image;

    li.appendChild(title);
    li.appendChild(price);
    li.appendChild(image);

    productList.appendChild(li);
}

db.collection('Products').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderProducts(doc);
    })
})
```